# To prove that $f(x)= |x|+|y|$ is not differentiable at origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To prove that $f(x)= |x|+|y|$ is not differentiable. In order to see differentiability i see taht i need to prove taht limit exists , but in that we have to find value of partials at origin which is my main problem.

How do i find partial derivative at origin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just consider the directional derivatives:

$$\lim_{h\to0, h>0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0, h>0}\frac{|h|}{h} = \lim_{h\to0, h>0}\frac{h}{h} = 1$$
and
$$\lim_{h\to0, h<0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0, h<0}\frac{|h|}{h} = \lim_{h\to0, h<0}\frac{-h}{h} = -1$$

This means even the partial derivatives wrt. $x$ do not exist.

Comment: Is this enough for a question of 6 points.I am having exam day after

Comment: I don't know if this is enough for a question of 6 points but it clearly shows that f is not differentiable at the origin and that no partial derivatives exist at the origin.